# ORACLE Select and group by excluding one field

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a very simple query (on Oracle 11g) to select 3 fields:

```
select field1, field2, field3, count(*) from table
where...
group by field1, field2, field3
having count(*) > 10;
```

Now, what I need, is exclude "field3" from the "group by" since I only need field 1 and 2 to be grouped, but I also need field3 in the output.
As far I know, all the fields in the select must be reported also in "group by", so how can I handle that?

Thanks
Lucas

Answer (score 3):

```
select t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, tc.Count
from table t
inner join (
    select field1, field2, count(*) as Count
    from table 
    where... 
    group by field1, field2 
    having count(*) > 10 
) tc on t.field1 = tc.field1 and t.field2 = tc.field2
```

Comment: Your query it doesn't work since report the same values twice! :-(<br/>

BTW, Assuming the table contains the following:<br/>

`code`FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3<br/>
1111    2222     1234<br/>
1111    9876     1234
1111    2222     1234`code`
With my simple query I got this result:
`code`FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  COUNT
1111    2222     1234    2
1111    9876     1234    1`code`
But since field1 and field3 are always the same, the count should be 3. But the question is, assuming I can create a query to do that, what about FIELD2 output?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [analytical version](http://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2009/12/26/sql-%E2%80%93-count-analytical-function-group-by-having/) of the "count" function:

```
select * from (
select field1, field2, field3, count(*) over(partition by field1, field2) mycounter
from table ) 
--simulate the having clause
where mycounter > 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't group by `field3` anymore, there can suddenly be different `field3` per group. You must decide which one to show, e.g. the maximum:

```
select field1, field2, max(field3), count(*) from table
where...
group by field1, field2
having count(*) > 10;
```

Comment: But that doesn't help when the result you want to show up under Field3 correspond to the max of another field. Example: If Field1 is an ID, Field2 a date, and Field3 some amount, I want the value of Field3 to be whatever corresponds to the Field2 max date, where Field1 is a repeated ID.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to handle that is to first isolate the Field1 and Field2 data and create a new table, then link it back to the original table adding in Field3.

```
Select Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2, Table1.Field3
From
(Select Field1, max(Field2) as Field2
From Table1) Table2
Where Table2.Field1 = Table1.Field1
And Table2.Field2 = Table1.Field2
Group By
Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2, Table1.Field3
```