# Exclude a column of select statement in group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which generates a report

```
select 
  cust.firstname as "FIRST NAME",
  cust.lastname as "LAST NAME",
  dept.name as "DEPARTMENT",
  subdept.name as "SUB DEPARTMENT",
  count(*) "cust type"
from cust
join dept on dept.deptid = cust.deptid
join subdept on subdept.deptid = cust.subdeptid
join custactivity on custactivity.custid = cust.custid
where custactivity.swipetime > (trunc(sysdate - 1))
group by cust.firstname,cust.lastname,dept.name,subdept.name
having count(*) > 5
order by "DEPARTMENT" ;
```

Now, I want to include the column "custactivity.swipetime" only in the select statement but not group by clause as it is a time field and I get incorrect results if I include that in group by clause. How's is it possible?

I tried the solution in [ORACLE Select and group by excluding one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995437/oracle-select-and-group-by-excluding-one-field)
but it didn't work out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which value would you want for this non-grouped-by column? If the value is non-unique, you may as well group by. If it has multiple values, which one would you expect?

Comment: Are you asking for Oracle or PostgreSQL? And what has PL/SQL to do with this? Don't tag products and languages not involved.

Comment: I removed the Postgres and PL/SQL tags as this is clearly an SQL only question for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

There can be many custactivities per customer. So you must tell the DBMS which swipetime to choose. For instance the latest:

```
, max(custactivity.swipetime) as "last swipe time"
```

---

In the comment below you say you want a result row per cust.firstname, cust.lastname, dept.name, subdept.name, *and* custactivity.swipetime. So swipetime must be added to the group by clause.

Here is your query with swipetime added to the group by clause. You need the analytic function SUM over your original group. And as you cannot use analytic functions in your having clause, you need a surrounding query.

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    cust.firstname as "FIRST NAME",
    cust.lastname as "LAST NAME",
    dept.name as "DEPARTMENT",
    subdept.name as "SUB DEPARTMENT",
    custactivity.swipetime as "SWIPE TIME",
    sum(count(*)) over (partition by 
                        cust.firstname, 
                        cust.lastname, 
                        dept.name, 
                        subdept.name) as "cust type"
  from cust
  join dept on dept.deptid = cust.deptid
  join subdept on subdept.deptid = cust.subdeptid
  join custactivity on custactivity.custid = cust.custid
  where custactivity.swipetime > (trunc(sysdate - 1))
  group by 
    cust.firstname, 
    cust.lastname, 
    dept.name, 
    subdept.name, 
    custactivity.swipetime
)
where "cust type" > 5
order by "DEPARTMENT";
```

Comment: I want all the instances...not just the latest one

Comment: You are getting one result row per firstname, lastname, dept name, and subdept name. You don't want to add swipetime to the group by clause, because then you'd get one result row per firstname, lastname, dept name, subdept name, and swipetime. So with your current grouping there can be several swipetimes for one result row. Do you want a column with a string containing all those swipetimes? Then you'd use `LISTAGG`. Or what else do you have in mind?

Comment: Suppose there are n swipe times for cutomer x;I want all the n swipe times for that customer with count being same.

As I dont want to count based on swipe time and just group by remaining columns except swipe time

Comment: Okay, that's a bit more complicated. Please see the query I posted.

Comment: Thank you so much.I will try that and see if it works

Comment: "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"
Getting this error at 
    subdept.name) as "cust type"

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help. I am not getting this error on my machine.